# Find all modes derived from a mode

Tags: major-mode, derived-mode

Is there any way to easily find all the modes that derive from a mode?

The closest I can get is to use `M-x apropros` and search for `-mode$` and manually comb through all defuns with the property `derived-mode-parent` and peek at them to see if they derive from the mode I am interested in. I suppose I could write a routine to do that quickly, but I'd rather not if I can help it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to write that code yourself, but I would suggest using `mapatoms` instead of any kind of `apropos` call. (And just process anything with a `derived-mode-parent` property, as you've already determined.)

Comment: You can use `derived-mode-p` instead of checking `derived-mode-parent`, but it's about the same thing. The hard part is finding "all modes" to test. A derived mode need not have a name that ends in `-mode`...

Comment: Of course, some of those derived modes may not be in your Emacs session yet, or may not be present on your machine (yet) either, so it also depends on how exhaustive you want to be.